# How to properly build the Docker with nodejs/ts?

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker

Been struggling for a couple days to run the project in prod and it just keeps showing different errors. The last one(hopefully) is:

```
> rimraf dist && tsc -p tsconfig.build.json
tsc-watch/test/fixtures/failing.ts(2,1): error TS1005: '}' expected.
```

But `tsconfig.build.json` is fine:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "test", "**/*spec.ts"]
}
```

It happens after I try to build/run the docker container with: 
`docker-compose up --force-recreate --build`

Here's what I have in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:11-stretch
ADD ./* $HOME/
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
CMD npm run start:prod
```

And the package.json

```js
{
  "name": "mvp-api",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "MVP API",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf dist && tsc -p tsconfig.build.json",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main.ts",
    "start:dev": "tsc-watch -p tsconfig.build.json --onSuccess \"node dist/main.js\"",
    "start:debug": "tsc-watch -p tsconfig.build.json --onSuccess \"node --inspect-brk dist/main.js\"",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main.js",
    "lint": "tslint -p tsconfig.json -c tslint.json",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^6.5.3",
    "@nestjs/core": "^6.5.3",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^6.1.1",
    "@nestjs/microservices": "^6.0.4",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^6.1.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^6.0.4",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^3.1.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^6.1.3",
    "@nestjs/websockets": "^6.0.4",
    "@nestrx/twilio": "0.0.2",
    "@types/mailgun-js": "^0.22.3",
    "@types/qrcode": "^1.3.4",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.513.0",
    "cache-manager": "^2.10.0",
    "cache-manager-mongodb": "^0.2.1",
    "cache-manager-redis-store": "^1.5.0",
    "class-transformer": "^0.2.3",
    "class-validator": "^0.10.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.0.0",
    "hbs": "^4.0.4",
    "is-base64": "^0.1.0",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.7.22",
    "mailgun-js": "^0.22.0",
    "mysql": "^2.17.1",
    "nestjs-config": "^1.4.3",
    "onesignal-node": "^2.1.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "qrcode": "^1.4.1",
    "randomstring": "^1.1.5",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "2.6.3",
    "rxjs": "6.4.0",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.0.7",
    "twilio": "^3.33.4",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.18",
    "vcard-generator": "0.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/testing": "6.1.1",
    "@types/cache-manager": "^2.10.0",
    "@types/express": "4.16.1",
    "@types/jest": "24.0.11",
    "@types/node": "11.13.4",
    "@types/randomstring": "^1.1.6",
    "@types/supertest": "2.0.7",
    "jest": "24.7.1",
    "prettier": "1.17.0",
    "supertest": "4.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "24.0.2",
    "ts-loader": "^6.0.4",
    "ts-node": "8.1.0",
    "tsc-watch": "2.2.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "3.8.0",
    "tslint": "5.16.0",
    "typescript": "3.4.3",
    "webpack": "^4.39.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.6",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

It used to build fine with these configurations but after purging all containers/images and trying to recreate everything it just doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to get it to run properly in prod?

Comment: Can you try excluding the `tsc-watch` folder as well? Looks like the error is coming from one of the TS files there and the `test` in the exclusion could possibly not really excluding the thing.

Comment: ok that did something and I get the terminal full of logs like `rxjs/operator/let.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/operator/let'` and `twilio/lib/rest/api/v2010/account/sip/credentialList.d.ts(12,10): error TS2440: Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'CredentialListInstance'.` and 1000+ others.

Comment: Ouch. Hmmmm. Aren't those under node_modules folder though? That's odd.

Comment: Okay how about this: explicitly include those that you actually need to build, instead of doing the exclude? `include: **/src/*` for instance.

Comment: yeah. Also everything runs/works fine on local machine so it must have something to do with configurations. I know ts shouldn't be installed in docker container but how come `tsc -p tsconfig.build.json` has to be executed if ts isn't there?

Comment: I get the same initial error if I remove exclude and add `"exclude":["**/src/*"]`

Comment: You need the tsc to build your code. That's vital to make a production build of your app. `"exclude":["**/src/*"]` should be `include` isntead of `exclude`. Try if that works.

Comment: oh yeah, it was include when I did that. Was just typing that again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201630/discussion-between-filip-luchianenco-and-edrian).

Comment: Now that's even odder. How come the test folder still get's included in the build? How does your project's folder structure look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was that the node_modules would keep copying over.

Adding a `.dockerignore` file with the following content solves the problem:

```
node_modules
```

Now I can run the docker container successfully.